# Access dbcontext at startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

.NET MVC5 Application using Identity 2.

I need to call a method of my service at application startup, but the method needs to access the database. where and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityModel.cs is the place needs modification

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

instead of default connection, you can create multiple environment variables. Hope this answered your question